# Resume Build in Jenkins after Failure

Tags: jenkins, build, jenkins-plugins

Is there any other way to resume Jenkins build after failure. My jenkins job took more than 3 hours to complete. It frequently fails due to some network issue. so i want to resume that job at that particular point of failure. Please give some suggestion to me

Comment: How should Jenkins know, where to continue? It assumes that a non-zero exit code is a failure. You can have retries, esp. when using [`retry`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-retry-code-retry-the-body-up-to-n-times) in [tag:jenkins-pipeline].

Comment: have you checked my answer from this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50732653/when-executing-jobs-in-jenkins-pipeline-and-a-job-is-failed-at-night-how-do-you/50732698#50732698)?