# When executing jobs in Jenkins pipeline and a job is failed at night how do you resume it in the same night?

Tags: selenium, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

When executing selenium jobs in Jenkins pipeline and a job is failed at night how do you resume it in the same night?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Naginator](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Naginator+Plugin) plugin to achieve your intended behavior. Configure it as follows:

> Install the plugin -> check the Post-Build action "Retry build
>   after failure" on your project's configuration page.

If the build fails, it will be rescheduled to run again after the time you specified. You can choose how many times to retry running the job. For each consecutive unsuccessful build, you can choose to extend the waiting period.